# iptable output rule blocks deluge webui

Tags: 16.10, iptables, openvpn, deluge

i'm new to linux so please forgive me if I lack proper terminology (which in turn makes accurate google searches pretty hard).

**Question: How to force deluge to tunnel all traffic via openvpn `tun0` (client using NordVPN service) allowing for local WebUi access at the same time?**

I've setup a deluged deamon on headless ubuntu 16.10.
In order to make deluge run only via openvpn tun0 i've added following rules to iptables:

```
 sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --gid-owner debian-deluged -o lo -j ACCEPT
 sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --gid-owner debian-deluged \! -o tun0 -j REJECT
```

An iptable checkup confirms those have been added

```
    sudo iptable -L
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 39M packets, 23G bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    10       0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            owner GID match 129
    11    9584  487K REJECT     all  --  *      !tun0   0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            owner GID match 129 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

Problem is, I now can't access deluge WebUi sitting on port 8112 from my laptop.

My guess would be, that I need also a "INPUT" rule to solve this, but I wasn't able to find any useful hint or solution.

Comment: For openvpn you will need only setup vpn zone in your firewall, allowing to forward traffic via tunnel. The vpn default setup allows traffic to local lan. For that you will need to delete your two rules and setup push list option local def in openvpn server config file.

Comment: Thank you for a hint. I'll google up " setup push list option local def in openvpn server config file" and see what comes up. Just to confirm: your suggested method will block any traffic (including torrent) when openvpn goes down for any reason and resume once openvpn is back?

Comment: Depending on the config your outbound traffic will be routed through openvpn server and its wan output

Comment: Ok, from my limited knowledge I think that your solution is valid for openvpn servers. I'm running a client, connecting to NordVPN and would like to use that as the only internet source for all torrent related traffic (and I don't mind rest of traffic, as long as local network stays accessible)

Comment: You can configure your client separately when your configuration does not contain push list directive.

Comment: @kukulo thanks for your replies, but honestly - I don't understand what to do. I'm new to linux and if i can't find a copy / paste or really simple solution / explanation there isn't much I can do.